# Coverart-browser crashes Rhythmbox 3.3

Tags: 16.04, rhythmbox, plugins

My Rhythmbox 3.3 crashes (starts, shows main window, disappears from sight) as soon as I include in the start process the well known and  proven plugin "coverart-browser" from fossfreedom.

Is there any help?

**EDIT:**

In Terminal I get this error messages:

```
benbenna@MusikantenThinkPad-T43:~$ rhythmbox

/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_widgets.py:26: PyGIWarning: Notify was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.

  from gi.repository import Notify

/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_covericonview.py:28: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.

  from gi.repository import PangoCairo

/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/coverart_browser/coverart_artistinfo.py:28: PyGIWarning: WebKit was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.

  from gi.repository import WebKit


(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen



(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen


(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen


(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen


(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen


(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen


(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen


(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Zur Wiedergabeliste hinzufügen


(rhythmbox:4696): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_reorder_child: assertion 'old_link != NULL' failed
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has any help - here is perhaps some solace:
[issue 387 on github](https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser/issues/387)